# Connect mysql databases in two oracle virtual machines

Tags: mysql, virtual-machine

I have created two different virtual machines.Both of them are running in ubuntu server and each has MySQL databases. One was installed with lamp and other was installed manually. What I want is connect those two database. Is it possible to do? If yes may I ask what are the possible solutions or perhaps may I ask for some tutorials. By the way I am using the Oracle Virtual Machine.

Thank you In advance.

Comment: Your question is regarding the MySql database. Please remove the oracle tag (this one is to oracle database and has nothing to do with oracle virtual machine)

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "connect"?

Comment: VM1 can access the database of the VM2

Comment: Thats really a matter of networking on the VM's and thier container software and security settings. You would just set it up so that you can hit the IP address of VM1 from VM2 and vice versa as well as configure it so that mysql is available on an accessible port (default is 3306). This question is really more appropriate for ServerFault or SuperUser

Comment: @prodigitalson Can I ask for some links for tutorial because i'm a newbie in using virtual machines and when I search in the net the search engines usually provide is about the azure virtual machine.

Comment: Yeah i have no clue about Oracle VM's... I've only used VM Ware and dabbled with Docker. That said the documentation appears to be [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/vm/documentation/index.html) and i think specifically you want [Chapter 4: Create a Virtual Machine Network](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E50245_01/E50248/html/vmgsg-network.html)

Comment: ok sir. I would read the documentation. Thank you for your help sir.